# Strange behavior when adding constraint to instance

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm using the [syntactic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/syntactic) library to work with ASTs. I'm getting some strange behavior, and I'm not what's happening.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, GADTs, FlexibleInstances,
    FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances #-}
module Foo where

import Data.Syntactic
import Data.Syntactic.Functional

data Const a where Const :: Const (Full a)
instance Render Const where renderSym Const = "const"

main :: ASTF Const Int
main = foo $ inj Const

class Foo dom where
  foo :: ASTF dom a -> ASTF dom a

instance --(Const :<: dom) => 
    Foo dom where
  foo node | Just Const <- prj node = error "PASS"
  foo _ = error "FAIL"

bar :: (Const :<: dom) => ASTF dom a -> ASTF dom a
bar node | Just Const <- prj node = error "PASS"
bar _ = error "FAIL"
```

***Question 1***

I can define a `Foo` instance *without* the constraint `Const :<: dom`, but I don't know of any way to make `bar` compile without that constraint (GHC suggests `IncoherentInstances` if I leave the constraint off of `bar`). What is different between `bar` and `foo` that allows me to not use the constraint with `foo`?

***Question 2***

Although I *can* define the `Foo` instance without the constraint, running `main` in the code above prints "FAIL". However, if I add (uncomment) the constraint `Const :<: dom` in the instance, `main` prints "PASS". What Haskell machinery makes it possible to add an unnecessary constraint and change the behavior? What specifically is happening in this example to cause this behavior? I suspect it might have something to do with overlapping/undecidable/incoherent instances in the Syntactic library. (Note: `bar` always prints "PASS".)

Comment: The type of `prj` is `Project sub sup => sup a -> Maybe (sub a)`. There is an instance which looks like `instance Project sub sup`. This instance works for any two types, which means it is always available, and it always returns Nothing. When you add the constraint `Const :<: dom`, this implies `Project Const dom`, which allows the compiler to use *that* instance, since it will pick the most specific instance in the presence of OverlappingInstances, and that instance returns `Just Const` for `prj (inj Const)`.

Comment: @user2407038 Good answer to Question 2. Do you also have an explanation as to why the behaviour is different between `foo` and `bar`? This currently looks quite strange to me, and I'm tempted to consider it as a GHC bug.

Comment: I'm tempted to agree. I see no reason that `bar` should not use the default most general instance the same as `foo` does. The documentation doesn't seem to indicate any reason for this.

Comment: I've opened https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9820